# paypal how to avoid double reply of PDT data

Tags: php, paypal

So after a user decides to buy something via paypal, he clicks the pay button, gets redirected to http://www.example.com/success.php which reads the GET from PayPal with txID, makes a POST to paypal to verify, gets the data and then the script adds the amount of money (mc_gross) to his "example.com" account. The problem is, the user can copy paste the URL of "http://www.example.com/success.php?tx=xxx..." and re-visit it, PDT will happily reply with the data again and another X amount will be added to the user in his "example.com" account. How do I avoid that ?

Comment: Use a POST request for things like this so copy-pasting the URL wouldn't generate the same request?

Comment: @apokryfos PayPal sends its info via GET initially, then from the GET parameters I take tx and POST it back to PayPal. That's how I do it. My problem is, the user can get the initial URL that paypal returns the user and re-visit it.

Comment: And you're sure PayPal would happily treat tx as a new transaction and not one that already took place?

Comment: @apokryfos Paypal will treat the second time tx as the one that already took place, yes and will reply with the transaction info that the user payed X sum. Ah, I figured it out, the first time it happens I should also log in my DB the txID so that a new amount cannot be added again with that ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was stupid, well should be after 12 hours of coding. The answer is simple, when the return URL (script) get the TX data and credits the user with X amount, it should also check whether that tx id has been used again before, if not log the TX id, so that the user will not use the return URL again to credit himself X amount again.

Close or delete the question please.